# How to do a Post while using RestKit

Tags: ios, post, restkit

I know there are multiple questions like this on the website, but none of the solutions work for me.

All I want to do is a simple post to a webservice using RestKit for iOS.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
     RKClient *client = [RKClient sharedClient];
            client.authenticationType = RKRequestAuthenticationTypeHTTPBasic;
            [client post:[ACCOUNT_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:@"/Register"] params:        

     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   _dateOfBirth.text, @"DOB",
                                   _emailAddress.text, @"Email",
                                   _firstName.text, @"FirstName",
                                   _lastName.text, @"LastName",
                                   _password.text, @"Password",
                                   _userName.text, @"UserName",
                                   nil] delegate:self];
```

I keep getting an error:
RKResponse.m:164 Asked if canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace: with authenticationMethod = NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust

Also when I started sniffing the packets sent from the simulator I realized that the POST is not sent at all.

Has someone faced this problem before? Please point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: If a POST isn't sent, what is? A GET or nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are setting the username and password properties of the client:

```
client.username = @"your_username"
client.password = @"your_password"
```